# Infineon IRS2008STRPBF Half Bridge Driver - What am I doing wrong?

Tags: power-electronics, motor-controller, half-bridge

I'm working on building a simple DC motor controller consisting of 2 half-bridges. I'm just going to show half, since that's all I've breadboarded at this point, but I can't get this chip to show any sign of life, and I'm wondering what I'm doing wrong.

This is the circuit I have, with the resistor & capacitor values noted:

[image: half-bridge-circuit]

And here's a link to the schematic above: https://www.flux.ai/jeremyblalock/h-bridge-test?editor=schematic

Regardless of the position of S1, J1 still reads 0V, and the gate voltages (relative to ground) both read as 0V. Not sure what I'm doing wrong, since this is very close the recommended circuit on [the datasheet](https://www.infineon.com/dgdl/Infineon-IRS2008%28S%2CM%29-DataSheet-v01_00-EN.pdf?fileId=5546d46269e1c019016ae5475e943bd3&redirId=115112).

Have also tried tying SD3 high, low, and disconnected, none of which caused any changes.

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: SD (shutdown) is actice low, so should be tied high. The IN pin does not look connected to the switch (in the link). The power source looks like a constant voltage source but is labeled as a constant current source. Did you try measuring other voltages or just the output?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: R1 and 2 should be around 22R. You’ll also need to feed it a pwm signal in order for the boost circuit to work - you can’t just give it a simple switch input. Breadboarding high speed, high current circuits is not recommended due to high resistance and inductive connections.